# Use of a joining comma with a sentence with a single subject and two verbs

Tags: commas

I've come across a few examples on this [website](https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/how-to-use-commas-to-join-two-complete-sentences/), but I am confused as to why some of them are correct and others are not.

Apparently, the following is correct.

> Agnes robbed the bank, and then she went out for a hamburger.

However, the following is not.

> Ella wrote a statement for the media, and then screamed at her press agent for an hour.

While I do understand the justification for the latter being incorrect (It's not actually two complete sentences as there is only a single subject), I don't understand why this does not apply to the first sentence. Surely that only has a single subject as well?

Comment: Agnes and she make for two subjects. The second sample may not require the comma, but it can add clarity. It's not wrong.

Comment: Yikes; that first reads really poorly to me and I'd recommend against it even if it's technically correct. I would say "Agnes robbed the bank, then went out for a hamburger" or many other variants --- this is just clunky. I agree with Yosef Baskin that this the second subject is an explicit *she*, whereas example 2 only has an *implicit* subject. If it were "and then she screamed," the same rule would presumably apply.

Comment: Want to clarify that if you do include *she* like the example you do need the *and* to avoid a comma splice. I specifically removed *both* the "and" and "she" from the sentence.